# R matrix: input zeros in columns with lowest values

Tags: r, matrix, input

I have a matrix nxn with numeric values. I need to find which are the 3 columns with the highest values per every row and inpout zeros in the rest of columns.

Eg, on row would be:

```
           a   b    r   t     y    n
user1    1.3   2    4   5.5   0    0
user2      8   0  1.5   5     3  7.2
```

The resulting matrix would be:

```
           a   b    r   t     y    n
user1      0   2    4   5.5   0    0
user2      8   0    0   5     0  7.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We loop through the rows of the `matrix` using `apply` (with `MARGIN=1`), `rank` the elements, create a logical vector (`< 4`), use `ifelse` to replace the elements that are not the highest 3, and transpose (`t`) the output.

```
m2 <- m1
m2[] <-t(apply(m1, 1, function(x)
         ifelse(rank(-x, ties.method='min') < 4, x, 0)))
m2
#      a b r   t y   n
#user1 0 2 4 5.5 0 0.0
#user2 8 0 0 5.0 0 7.2
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(dplyr)
m1[ave(m1, row(m1), FUN=min_rank) < 4] <- 0
```

Answer (score 4):

If efficiency matters, I would try the `matrixStats` package

```
m[matrixStats::rowRanks(m) < 4] <- 0
m
#       a b r   t y   n
# user1 0 2 4 5.5 0 0.0
# user2 8 0 0 5.0 0 7.2
```

If ties matter, use the `ties.method` argument